# Blog Title not showing up on main Blog page

Tags: title, get-the-title

I cannot get the main blog page with the current blog to show the current blog title.  It shows on all other pages, just not the current/most recent blog.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<div id="page">

    <div id="contentleft">

        <?php if ( $paged < 2 ) { // Do stuff specific to first page?>

        <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=featured&showposts=1');
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
         $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

        <div class="featurepost" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p class="postinfo">By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?> in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?><?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', ''); ?></p>

            <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content('Read the rest'); ?>
                </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What title are you referring to? i assume you do not mean a post title...

Comment: yes, the post title...www.stevekrautcoaching.com/blog

Comment: What file is the code above from?

Comment: Above is from the index.php file

Comment: www.stevekrautcoaching.com/blog is't loading any div with the id 'featurepost'. And if there is a problem with the dynamic codes, the HTML won't be affected as the code mentioned above. I found no `<h2>` using Firebug into your blog URL. The hierarchy I found is:

Comment: `<div id="contentleft">
<div id="post-1891" class="post">
<div class="entry">
</div>
<div class="navigation">
</div>`

Comment: Thank you.  However, I don't do code, but I know where to look.  I have no clue how to fix this.  Could you/someone explain that to me in english/Noob?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that first page is your index.php, and I would guess that the code within that file is different from single.php, which is the file used by pages 2 onwards.

Comment: here is the single.php code:

Comment: <div id="page">

  <div id="contentleft">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

     <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

     <p class="postinfo">By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?> in <?php the_category(', ') ?><?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', ''); ?></p>
   
     <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content(); ?>

Comment: @NatalieOlson - please update your questions, rather than adding long code in comments - it's very hard to read here..